# Connecting to VPN programmatically with PPTP in iOS

Tags: objective-c, vpn, ipsec, pptp

I want to connect through vpn using pptp connection programmatically.

Is this Possible?
So far I have find 
http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/
but here only IPSec and IKEv2 protocol supported.

So is there any solution for pptp?

Thanks .

Comment: have you found a solution? i am facing the same problem.